# Python - Why doesnt my newly-unioned set not return value: True

Tags: python, int, set, boolean

Just curious really, running through some basic concepts and looking some of your friendly help.

I'm really just wondering why my newly unified/unioned/joined set isn't returning my True value as expected but has returned my False value.

I have the following code:

```
mySet1 = {1, 2, "Hello}

mySet2 = {"World!", 2.5, True, False}

myUnion = mySet1.union(mySet2)

print (myUnion)
```

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: Because `True == 1` and `False == 0`, (Note,  `issubclass(bool, int) is True`)

Comment: In other words, in Python's class hierarchy, *boolean objects are integer objects*. Some people don't like this, indeed, I personally think it isn't ideal, but it is mostly a result of historical considerations, the `bool` type wasn't added until [Python 2.3](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-bool.html) and before that, `1` and `0` were used as True and False, much like in C, so the `bool` type was made to be compatible with previous usage.

Comment: Strictly speaking, hashing-based containers like sets don't care about the type *per se*. Any object that that hashes to the same value and returns `True` for `==` will be treated as the same in a hashing based container.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the underlying definitions of True and False.

```
>>> {True, 1}
{True}
>>> {False, 0}
{False}
```

Note that this is fine, because you can still test for the presence of those entries:

```
>>> 1 in {True, 1}
True
>>> 0 in {False, 0}
True

>>> 1 in {True}
True
>>> 0 in {False}
True
```

Comment: This is great, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because True is 1 as integer.

True and 1 is same.

If you remove 1 from mySet1, True will be shown.